# How can I show checked CheckBox in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a parameter field 'EL' and formula field 'FormulaEL'. I write a formula as follows:

```
 if {?EL}=1 then chr(254)
```

In preview the report shows checked CheckBox. but the problem is that if I run the program it is displayed as ( þ ) , not as checkedbox. How to solve the problem so that it is displayed as checked CheckBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, a checkbox just evaluate to 'r' and set the font in the report for that field to webdings.

You could go a step further and use an image of a check instead, and conditionally surpress it when it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

CHR(254) is a checkmark in the WindDings font but is the symbol you show above in most other fonts.  It may be that you have Wingdings on the design PC but don't have Wingdings available at runtime so it is substituting another font.  This font should be available on most windows PCs. You will have to install it if it is not available.

https://www.microsoft.com/typography/Fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1698

Comment: How to get Wingdings available at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

if ISNULL({coulmn_name}) then Chr(251) //shows x mark on the report
else if{coulmn_name} ='column_value' then Chr(252)//shows Tick mark in the report
// And change font to wingdings for the field in details section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).